# Есть ли альтернатива history.pushState

Tags: html5-history-api, javascript

Дело в том, что на главной работает а в рубриках нет:

```
сайт.ru/page/2 - (правильно (это для главной))

сайт.ru/article/page/2 - (Нужно для рубрик)
сайт.ru/page/2 - (Получается для рубрик не правильно)

history.pushState('', '', '/page/' + current_page);
```

Comment: @romeo Получение текущего урла на js:

    window.location.href

Comment:     history.pushState('', '', window.location.href + '/page/' + current_page);

@romeo в рубриках все работает а на главной "сайт.ru//page/2". Если сделать "page/" - то в рубриках "сайт.ru/articlepage/2".

Comment: @rodion Смотрите в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href.replace(/\/+$/,'');

history.pushState('', '', currentUrl + '/page/' + current_page);
```

Только могут быть нюансы. К примеру, URL может содержать аргументы `?arg=7`. Используйте `window.location.pathname` вместо `window.location.href`.

Comment: @romeo спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Так и пишите

```
history.pushState('', '', '/article/page/' + current_page);
```

**Обновление**

Вычисляйте нужный url при помощи php\js и подставляйте его в качестве параметра.

Или пишите относительный url

```
history.pushState('', '', 'page/' + current_page); // Может поможет
```

Comment: @naym так может быть не только article (article, video и т.д.) + для главной тогда работать не будет.